# Gitlab mails are not received

Tags: postfix, centos7, gitlab

I've installed `gitlab` on a `centOS 7` server with omnibus package but when I try to create an user on `gitlab` the mails are not sent.
I've opened the post 25  with :

```
sudo firewall-cmd   --add-port=25/tcp
```

But I'm not sure about the psotfix configuration (set hosts,user,password)

I'm using the docs config

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true;
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = 'localhost';
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25;
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = 'localhost';
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false;
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_ssl'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_force_ssl'] = false
```

Comment: `sudo firewall-cmd   --add-port=25/tcp` opens port 25 for incoming SMTP traffic, which is generally not needed when you only send mail from a server. - Do your log files contain any relevant details/errors/warnings?

Comment: I have this message on logs `warning: Illegal address syntax from localhost[::1] in MAIL command: <gitlab@myip>`

Comment: It seems as if your Email is accepted but the Local Server but cannot be forwarded due to Postfix Configuration Issue. It is certainly not a Firewall Issue.

Comment: if you try to send an Email to a User using the IP Address of its Machine Postfix will give you an Error: `Jul  2 15:27:14 mailserver postfix/smtpd[4371]: warning: Illegal address syntax from mailserver[127.0.0.1] in RCPT command: <user@the.ip.add.ress>` the recipient needs a Machine with Canonical Name or some name that can be resolved with an DNS Request.